# Need example sentence with poníamos (poner)

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras

Can someone give me a sample sentence with this form of poner: poníamos?

Por ejemplo...

[Inglés]

> We were putting the tools in the wrong box

[Español]

> Nosotros estábamos poniendo las herramientas en la caja equivocada
> o
> Nosotros poníamos las herramientas en la caja equivocada

Comment: You have given an example sentence so it is not clear to me what your question is. Do you have some doubt about your example?

Comment: Drop the nosotros. No one would use it there.  **Poníamos mucho pan en la sopa cuando era joven**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in the CREA (http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html) you get hundreds of examples:

[image]

and if you click in **poniamos** in any of the examples, it shows you the paragraph, not yust part of the sentense.